# How to create a desktop shortcut as a url file with parameters

Tags: c#, url

I want to create a shortcut on the desktop to a app with c#. Here is my code:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DesktopPath + @"\" + theData.Name + ".url");
sw.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
sw.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + @"C:\Program Files\some Software\app.exe -r " + theData.Name + " -u " + theData.User);
sw.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
sw.Close();
```

This works fine, accepting the parameters (-r, -u or other stuff). With parameters there appears a error that the **file was not found** and I should be sure about the spelling an try it again. Sorry the error message is not in English so I have to translate. [image]

If I write it without parameters to the url file it works.

In the cmd the parameters works.

Comment: Please supply what the error was

Comment: well file was not found.

Comment: I meant the actual output error (I've seen cases in the past when people misinterpret the output when they get an error) not the description of the error

Comment: okay, I added a picture

Comment: You probably needs to create an actual shortcut (lnk) instead of a url file.

Comment: But why don't you just create the shortcut the easy way instead of coding it?

Comment: because I want to add it as a feature in an application

Answer (score 0):

This may sound overly simplified; however, I would recommend that you give this a shot.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(DesktopPath + @"\" + theData.Name + ".url");
sw.WriteLine("[InternetShortcut]");
sw.WriteLine("URL=file:///" + @"""C:\Program Files\some Software\app.exe"" -r " + theData.Name + " -u " + theData.User);
sw.WriteLine("IconIndex=0");
sw.Close();
```

This is placing quotes around the application file path allowing a seperation of information from the arguments that you're passing.

Comment: It does not work (windows 10 20H2). Full string in URL= is interpreted as path to application to execute. Despite any number of quotes. Example: URL=file:///"C:\SF\opc\OpcCn.exe" -u=dev1 -p=1!965d93a6~12UzMhMqoD - Windows reports file is not file and show full url (but exe is exists)